# Scala assign inside an if condition

Tags: scala

```
val flag = false

if (val data = flag) {
  println(data)
}
```

Is it possible to assign the `flag` inside a if statement and get evaluated automatically in Scala?

Comment: Why would you want to write code like that? Inside the body of the `if`, `data` would always be `true`, so why would you want to have the `val data`?

Comment: It is still very unclear, what you try to achieve here. Instead of assigning `data` to the value of `flag` you could just use flag, which is in scope anyway. Please clarify what you want to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes but it doesn't escape the scope so you cannot use it in body of the if

```
if ({val data = true; data}) 
  println("data was true")
```

The assignment doesn't return a value but you can return it instead. Better to do something like

```
def test(data: Boolean) {
  if (data) {/* data in scope */} 
  else      {/* data in scope */}}
```

Comment: From you first sample code, is it possible to use the `data` inside the whole `if `block?

Comment: No unfortunately, it is only in scope inside the braces, if you need to assign and test then use in the body of the `if`, then it looks like you should declare a `var` (which requires a throw away assignment) in the outer scope containing the `if`. Using `var`s is something more of a consideration than being able to assign, test and then use in the scope of an `if`'s condition section however.

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice extension function which could help you with your case and many others. You can implement it with the following implicit conversion:

```
implicit class AnyExtensions[A](val x: A) extends AnyVal {
  def asSatisfying(p: A => Boolean): Option[A] =
    if (p(x)) Some(x) else None
}
```

Having it imported in scope you can do the following with your example:

```
flag.asSatisfying(_).foreach(println)
```

There are some better use cases for it explained in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12055571/485115).

The main merit of this function is that it allows you to effectively eliminate the need to introduce intermediate variables, thus providing you with ability to solve any "if-else" logic as a single line expression.